# About the separation of strings in a loop in R

Tags: r

I want to return a vector of strings of the elements in numerical vector `v` repeated the same amount of times as the value of the element and I have to use nested for loops for this.

Here is my code:

```
ReturnValueTimes <- function(v) {
  emptyString <- ""
  for(i in 1:length(v)){
    for(j in 1:v[i]){
      emptyString <- c(emptyString, v[i])
      repeatedNumbers <- paste(emptyString, collapse =  "")
    }
  }
  return(repeatedNumbers)
}
```

Test case for this:

```
> ReturnValueTimes(c(2,4,3))
[1] "224444333"
However, I want this to be something like:
> ReturnValueTimes(c(2, 4, 3))
[1] "22"   "4444" "333" 
> ReturnValueTimes(c(7, 1))
[1] "7777777" "1"
```

What conditions (statements) should I add in my code to separate the strings? Or change something to get the desired result?

Comment: This works for the specific test case,   what about my code?

Answer (score 1):

Well I do not understand why you should write an R function for this since there is already one in base r

```
strrep(x<-c(5,2,3),x)
[1] "55555" "22"    "333"  
strrep(x<-c(7,4,9),x)
[1] "7777777"   "4444"      "999999999"
```

Although you can still write yours:

```
ReturnValueTimes=function(x)strrep(x,x)
ReturnValueTimes(c(5,2,3))
[1] "55555" "22"    "333"
```

Now this is how you could have written your code:

```
ReturnValueTimes3 <- function(v) {
  store_here=character(length(v))# A character vector which will store
  for(i in 1:length(v)){
    emptyString <- ""#This is defined inside the first loop in order to rewrite its value after the inner loop is done
    for(j in 1:v[i]){
      emptyString <- c(emptyString, v[i])
      repeatedNumbers <- paste(emptyString, collapse =  "")
    }
   store_here[i] <- repeatedNumbers
  }
  return(store_here)
}

ReturnValueTimes3(c(3,4,5,6))
[1] "333"    "4444"   "55555"  "666666"
```

or you can do:

```
sapply(c(3,4,5,6),function(x)paste0(rep(x,x),collapse=""))
[1] "333"    "4444"   "55555"  "666666"
```

If you wanted to write yours but avoiding explicit `for loop` (includes the *apply family)

```
ReturnValueTimes2=function(x){
pattern=paste0("(\\d{",x,"})",collapse="")
substitution=paste0("\\",1:length(x),collapse=" ")
vect=paste0(rep(x,x),collapse = "")
strsplit(sub(pattern,substitution,vect)," ")[[1]]
}
 ReturnValueTimes2(c(5,3,4,6))
[1] "55555"  "333"    "4444"   "666666"
```

Comment: If you feel that this did answer your question you can accept it as a sign of it is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

Use the map functions in purrr

```
library(tidyverse)
ReturnValueTimes <- function (vec) map_chr(vec, function(x) str_c(rep(x, x), collapse = ""))
ReturnValueTimes(c(2, 3, 4))
#> [1] "22"   "333"  "4444"
```

Created on 2018-02-03 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.1.1.9000).